# How to resolve java.net.SocketException Permission Denied error?

Tags: android-emulator

I have already included the Internet Permissions in the andoird manifest page, still the error seems to persist. I am also recieveing an unknown host excption in the similar code. Kindly guide me through! Ty! :)

```
package name.id;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.*;
import org.ksoap2.transport.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstPage extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

  TextView tv;
  Button bu;
  EditText et;

  private static final String SOAP_ACTION="http://lthed.com/GetFullNamefromUserID";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME="GetFullNamefromUserID";
    private static final String NAMESPACE="http://lthed.com";
    private static final String URL="http://vpwdvws09/services/DirectoryService.asmx";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        bu=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bu.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
        tv.setText("");
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {           
        // creating the soap request and all its paramaters
        SoapObject request= new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        //request.addProperty("ID","89385815");// hardcoding some random value
        //we can also take in a value in a var and pass it there


        //set soap envelope,set to dotnet and set output
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet=true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE obj = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        //to make call to server
        try
        {
            obj.call(SOAP_ACTION,soapEnvelope);// in out parameter
            SoapPrimitive resultString=(SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            //soapObject or soapString
            tv.setText("Status : " + resultString);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            tv.setText("Error : " + e.toString());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was being thrown because of an error in the URL. The URL needed my IP address to function properly rather than the URL i was providing because that the webservice was not able to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added Internet permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Yes! Like i mentoned I have added the internet permissions in the manifest page too. Still it seems to be throwing an error. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what KSOAP2 version you are using error may vary.

Its recommend that use KSOAP2 v3+ lib.

Simply use following code to override...

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

and also use...